# Deaemon thread in Java created or not?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am confused regarding daemon threads in Java.  Somewhere it says that a daemon thread is not  created but only control, and someone else says that daemon threads can also be created.  But how?

Comment: Please don't state "please reply satisfactory answer" in your question.

Comment: Daemon threads are not as special as you might imagine.  They are regular threads with a flag set which has a particular meaning. I think the confusion comes from imagining it is something more.

Answer (score 4):

Daemon thread is just a regular thread. The only difference that it does not prevent application from terminating. Application is terminated if all its non daemon threads have finished.